# return boolean while comparing strings as null or empty

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I am trying to migrate the below code to java 8

```
 private boolean test(String id1, String id2) {

        if(id2== null || id2.isEmpty()) return true;
        return id1.equals(id2);
    }
```

Solution tried

```
Optional.ofNullable(id2).map(String::isEmpty).orElse(id2.equals(id1));
```

The above solution  doesnot work when

```
id2 is null 
id2 is equal to id1
```

Comment: why cannot you use normal java, I mean here transforming to an Stream is not giving you anything positive It looks the same, or even more cumbersome. I would go for using eventually Strings.isNullOrEmpty() from guava

Comment: `return id2 == null || id2.isEmpty() || id2.equals(id1);` is concise, efficient, and valid Java 8 syntax.

Comment: @Holger just what I was thinking when I saw all this "trying to migrate the below code to java 8"... huh seriously...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Optional's are not meant to replace simple `if` checks. You're essentially "migrating" to a less readable and efficient solution.

If I were you I'd stick with your current solution as it's the *better* option, but if you want to code golf a little bit then you can do as @Holger has shown in the comments:

```
return id2 == null || id2.isEmpty() || id2.equals(id1);
```

Answer (score 2):

The `Function` passed to `map` is evaluated when the `Optional` is not empty (i.e. when `id2 != null`).

Therefore it should be:

```
private static boolean test(String id1, String id2) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(id2)
                   .map(id -> id.isEmpty() || id.equals(id1)) // return true if id2 
                                                              // is empty or equal 
                                                              // to id1
                   .orElse(true); // return true when id2 == null
}
```

Note that there's a slight change of behavior compared to your original code. In your original code you'll get a `NullPointerException` if `id1 == null` (unless you change `id1.equals(id2)` to `id2.equals(id1)`). In the `Optional` version, you won't.

Comment: should it not be .orElse(false)

Comment: orElse is executed when id2 == null, and you wanted to return true in that case. @coder25

Comment: upvote for the last edit, the comments makes it more meaningful and easy to understand

Comment: @nullpointer just wondering, would [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52699089/1059372) be more readable? (you don't have to upvote, seriously, I'm just interested)

Comment: @Eugene you mean, you are wondering which is less unreadable?

Comment: @Holger )))) the least of the evils I guess, damn that's a good point

Comment: @Eugene Well exactly what I meant by easy to understand as pointed by Holger, since readability of the above code is as complex as the solution by yours. Not that they are incorrect, just that prior to those comments by Eran, I found it literally tough to even relate the same logic with question.

Answer (score 0):

How about this instead:

```
private static boolean test(String left, String right) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(right)
            .map(String::isEmpty)
            .orElse(true)
            || left.equals(right);
}
```